# Stall bar exercises

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, exercise-equipment

I recently purchased stall bars for my home gym. What exercises can I do on them? Are there resources for progressive routines available somewhere? I haven’t been able to come across much other than a handful of YouTube videos.

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with stall bars. Are you able to link a picture or web page so we are talking about the same equipment?